# Mute Audio of a partcipant in group call based on userId (currentConference.current?.sendAudio(isMuted, userID))

Tags: react-native, voximplant

We have a requirement where we need to mute audio for a certain section of users in our Conference call. Can we have something like

```
currentConference.current?.sendAudio(isMuted, userID);
```

instead of

```
currentConference.current?.sendAudio(isMuted);
```